# Vue.js - cannot set radio button by default

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

[Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio) says that if initial value of v-model does not matches radio values, it will be displayed as unselected. I think that I did everything correctly but the radio Public is still not checked by default.

Component Radio:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="radio"
      :id="identifier"
      :value="identifier"
      :name="name"
      ref="radio"
      @input="updateRadio()"
      :checked="checked"
    >
    <label :for="identifier">
      <span>{{label}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["value", "name", "identifier", "label", "checked"],

  methods: {
    updateRadio() {
      this.$emit("input", this.$refs.radio.value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Vue usage

```
<Radio v-model="share" identifier="public" label="Public" name="share"/>
<Radio v-model="share" identifier="private" label="Private" name="share"/>

export default {
  name: "SignUpForm",
  components: {
    Radio
  },
  data: () => ({
    share: "public"
  })
};
```

I have looked to other relevant questions but I do not see a difference

- [how to make radio button checked by default in vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150231/how-to-make-radio-button-checked-by-default-in-vuejs)
- [Vue.js Bootstrap 4 , cannot check radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720800/vue-js-bootstrap-4-cannot-check-radio-button)

Fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-antonelli-yoblx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your component radio change the checked directive value into :checked="value"

Radio.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="radio"
      :id="identifier"
      :value="identifier"
      :name="name"
      ref="radio"
      @input="updateRadio()"
      :checked="value === identifier"
    >
    <label :for="identifier">
      <span>{{label}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["value", "name", "identifier", "label", "checked"],

  methods: {
    updateRadio() {
      this.$emit("input", this.$refs.radio.value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I Update it. sorry I think it's because the checked directive is boolean and now I added a condition to check.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I tried boolean types originally without luck as well.